# Herokuにgradleを使用したJavaServletアプリをデプロイしたが,実行時にエラーが出ます

Tags: java, heroku, gradle, servlet

HerokuでJavaServletで作成したプロジェクトをアップロードしたのですが,ブラウザから閲覧しようとしたところ『Application error』という表示が出てWebアプリが実行されません.

Heroku管理画面のActivityを見るとビルドとデプロイには成功しているようです.

```
-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
-----> executing ./gradlew stage
   :clean UP-TO-DATE
   :copyToLib
   :compileJava
   :processResources NO-SOURCE
   :classes
   :war
   :stage

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 15s
   4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
   Done: 76.5M
   -----> Launching...
   Released v20
   https://rocky-sands-26639.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Macのターミナルの

```
$heroku logs
```

で確かめてみたところ以下のエラーメッセージを確認できました.どうすれば,このエラーを解決できますか？

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
```

こちらのサイトに書かれている情報に基づいた手順で,Webアプリをデプロイしています.参考サイトではmavenを使用していますが,ソースコードではgradleを使用しています.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku#using-webapp-runner-to-deploy-war-files

ソースコード
https://github.com/fruitwater/heroku-servlet-gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

英語版のStackOverFlowで同じ質問をしたところ解決しました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237040/javaservlet-project-with-gradle-on-heroku-didnt-run

まずは、Procfileへ `--port $PORT` を加えて、次のようにします。

```
web: java -jar build/server/webapp-runner-*.jar --port $PORT build/libs/*.war
```

その後、コマンドに入力時に　`heroku ps:scale web=0` としていたところを
`heroku ps:scale web=1`　に変更したところ解決しました。